# Firebase and Language-Based Notifications: Sending Messages in Users' Preferred Languages

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm working on a social media app for Android using Kotlin, and I'm sending notifications to specific users within the app using Firebase Cloud Messaging and tokens. The app supports multiple languages, and what I aim to achieve is sending notifications to the recipient's device in their preferred language. How can we do this? I'm considering capturing the user's device language when they sign up, log in, or each time they access the app, and storing this information in Firebase. Then, I'd use this data when sending notifications. However, I'm open to different or more efficient suggestions and recommendations.

Comment: If you have an approach in mind that works for your app, it's probably best to (try and) implement that approach. If you then run into trouble, it's much more likely that someone here can help.